# Can't access Wordpress installed in Docker container

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

New to Docker and not fully understand it, bear with me if my expressions are confusing/wrong. I have a Ubuntu box on Azure with public IP address assigned. Then I putty into the box and install apache, php. I also installed Docker and Docker-compose. I am following [this official tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/#build-the-project) to install wordpress(on port 8000). When installation finishes I can see the default apache ubunto page at http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, but I am unable to access the website at http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000. What's the reason for not being able to access it? I can't find any relevant tutorial as most tutorials are doing it on localhost hence not referable. This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: wordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data:
```

docker ps outputs following:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                            NAMES
07d669b9f95e        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin   "/run.sh supervisord…"   10 hours ago        Up 10 hours         9000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   wp_phpmyadmin_1
5ff939494739        wordpress:latest        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 hours ago        Up 11 hours         0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp             wp_wordpress_1
479826f7cfb8        mysql:5.7               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   11 hours ago        Up 11 hours         3306/tcp, 33060/tcp              wp_db_1
```

Solution: At last I managed to make it work by opening up the port in Azure.

Comment: Could you display the result of your `docker ps` command? Also, on which OS are you running Docker from?

Comment: @Mornor edited for docker ps result

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with docker as long as the ports are exposed and you can see the content in the host machine

the problem is probably with the host machine, which should expose 8000 port

i'm not familiar with Azure, but i'm guessing port 80 is exposed by default, so try changing

```
 ports:
   - "8000:80"
```

to

```
 ports:
   - "80:80"
```

and call the machine using port 80 (which is http default)

Comment: I get this when I change it to 80: `ERROR: for wp_wordpress_1  Cannot start service wordpress: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint wp_wordpress_1 (xxxxxxxxxxxxxx): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use`